# OAuth2 support through library returns The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have spreadsheets that need to be converted to PDF by various users in my organisation. In order to do that I am trying to use OAuth2 (https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2).

When I am using it in a main spreadsheet embedded script it works. However I am trying to move the OAuth2 code to a separate library as there will be many spreadsheets that will need the same functionality. When I am using this library I am getting the message "The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again."

The library code:

```
var PROPERTY_KEY = "ExportPdfOauth2";

function initialStore() {
  setAuthenticationPackage_( {
    clientId : '10511......b43bu.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret : 'WYUsq...-h_',
    projectKey : 'MxJ.......xOvW',
    scopes : ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/']
  });
}

function setAuthenticationPackage_(package) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(PROPERTY_KEY, JSON.stringify(package));
}

function getAuthenticationPackage_() {
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(PROPERTY_KEY);
  return p ? JSON.parse(p) : {};
}

function getExportPdfService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.

  var package = getAuthenticationPackage_();

  return OAuth2.createService('exportPdf')

      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(package.clientId)
      .setClientSecret(package.clientSecret)

      // Set the project key of the script using this library.
      .setProjectKey(package.projectKey)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      .setScope(package.scopes)

      // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
      // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

      // Requests offline access.
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var exportPdfService = getExportPdfService();
  var isAuthorized = exportPdfService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Failure');
  }
}

function getExportPdfRequest() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var exportPdfService = getExportPdfService();
  if (!exportPdfService.hasAccess()) {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate('Authorisation required in order to enable conversion to pdf. You will need to perform the operation again once the authorisation is complete.')+
      '<br /><br />'+
      '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">'+
      'Authorise'+
      '</a>');
    template.authorizationUrl = exportPdfService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
    return null;
  }

  var request = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + exportPdfService.getAccessToken()
    }
  };

  return request;
}
```

The library is called by the embedded script as follows (please note that I put a callback function here that will call back the library):

```
function test(){
  var id = 'ABCD.....'; // Spreadsheet to be converted to pdf
  var name = 'test.pdf';
  var domain = 'XXXXX';

  var pdfContent = spreadsheetToPDF(id,domain,name);
  if (pdfContent) DocsList.createFile(pdfContent);
}

// Convert spreadsheet to PDF file.
function spreadsheetToPDF(id,domain,name) {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var request = testPdfLib.getExportPdfRequest();
  if (!request) return null;

  //define the params URL to fetch
  var params = '?fitw=true&exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&gridlines=false&pagenum=CENTER';
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/"+domain+"/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/export"+params;

  //fetching file url
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, request);
  blob = blob.getBlob().setName(name);

  //return file
  return blob;
}

function authCallback(request) {
  testPdfLib.authCallback(request);
}
```

I have also looked at another post at [How to correctly construct state tokens for callback urls in Managed Libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867189/how-to-correctly-construct-state-tokens-for-callback-urls-in-managed-libraries) but still can not figure out what I am doing wrong as I have provided the callback function at the main calling script. At the developers console my REDIRECT URIS points to the library. I tried to point it to the main script but I get the same results (though I wouldn't like to do so as the script will be copied by many users and it will be impossible to create a new client Id for each instance of the calling script).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: keep in mind that script properties can be for the script or for the library depending on where you call it from. so you cant just move code to the library as-is.

Comment: No sure I follow Zig. Can you elaborate and how does it effect the OAuth2?

Comment: not sure if that is the cause of your issue, but look at where the tokens are saved in script properties. make sure its the correct script properties (library or script)

Comment: The script properties are only declared and used by the library testPdfLib. They are not suppose to be available to the calling embedded script.

Comment: Still need help here!