# Apps script throws 'invalid state token' after autorization on consent screen

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I wish to authorize my webapp to create a folder in the user's appfolder to hold the app's data files.

To do this, I need to request the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder`

So far I have the following code:

```
var CLIENT_ID            = '3941...';
var CLIENT_SECRET        = 'DY_P...';
var SCRIPT_ID            = '1XAF...';

var appfolder_scope     = 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.appfolder';
var redirectURI         = 'https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F'+ SCRIPT_ID + '%2Fusercallback';
var AuthEndpoint        = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';



function getCallbackURL(callbackFunction) {

   var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();      // Ends in /exec (for a web app)
   url = url.slice(0, -4) + 'usercallback?state='; // Change /exec to /usercallback
   var stateToken = ScriptApp.newStateToken()
        .withMethod(callbackFunction)
        .withTimeout(120)
        .createToken();
   return url + stateToken;
}


function generateAuthRequestURL() {
  var AuthRequest = AuthEndpoint;
  var Query = '?'
      + 'scope=profile%20' + appfolder_scope
      + '&state=' + getCallbackURL(cb)
      + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI
      + '&response_type=code'
      + '&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID
    //+ '&login_hint=...%40gmail.com'
      ;
  AuthRequest += Query;
  Logger.log(AuthRequest);      
  return AuthRequest;
}

function cb(response) {
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

When I click on the url generated by the `generateAuthRequestURL()` it takes me to the consent screen where I click allow. But then every time I get 'The state token is invalid or has expired'.

The webapp is published and I have tested both the exec and dev versions with the same result. I have also tried with and without a login_hint.

I have also experimented with [Apps-Script-Folder-Library](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Appfolder-Library) as well as [gdrive-appdata](https://github.com/adrianbota/gdrive-appdata). I couldn't get the first one to work, and the second one I don't even know how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1/issues/2), make sure that you've put the project key into the related field. This error may occur when the key changed after making a copy of the script.

You can also check on this [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1/issues/3) which suggested to ensure that you are using the right project key.

Here are some related forums which might also help:

- [Issues with OAuth 2.0 Library for Google Apps Scripts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clio-developers/vyiMSjlkvEo)
- [OAuth2 support through library returns The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267570/oauth2-support-through-library-returns-the-state-token-is-invalid-or-has-expired)