# OAuth2 flow on Android

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I've got the full authorization working - on any browser. With any given OAuth2 server, I'm able to authenticate. However, when trying to authorize via Android, the only response I ever get, from scripts.google.com, is "The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again."

After inspecting my device through my WebIDE, I found that I never originate from scripts.google.com, it just opens a new window straight to oauth.myserver.com?state=abc&redirect_uri=https://scripts.google.com/...

Could that be the case? In the browser, you 'originate' from scripts.google.com, so the state is saved as a session variable. Upon returning, the state in the URL matches the one saved, so that's all good. But, on Android, there's no state set in scripts.google.com, because it's a completely new window with no state, and all you've got the is the redirect URI.

I've tried opening it in a WebView, hoping that would at least work, but that's not an option. Unsetting the default browser, only gives me the option to open it either in Firefox or in Chrome.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This eventually solved itself. It didn't work, and a few weeks later it did. I'm suspecting Google fixed something on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth1/issues/2), make sure that you've put the project key into the related field. You may encounter this error when making a copy of the script and when the key changed. You may also check this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288565/apps-script-throws-invalid-state-token-after-autorization-on-consent-screen). Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, none are relevant to me. Their flow didn't work in any given situation, if it wasn't the developer executing the action. The first link, I wouldn't even know what the project key is, or what the related field is. They also speak of OAuth1, rather than OAuth2.